# echo something out MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a question with answers out of my database. I just want to get one thing out of the database and not with a row. I thought this would work but it puts out this: Resource id #4 can someone explains what I am missing.

Thanks :)

```
    <?php 
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    mysql_select_db('lotto');   
    $sql = 'SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD FROM vraag1';
    $test = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $test;   

?>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. Also what you're missing is `$test` is a query result set not a string that can be echoed. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli#t=201702220849069806914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As said at least 10000 times everywhere in internet, never use MySQL_ ! (If your are trying to learn something new by using tutorials over internet, don't use old ones)**

*I recommend to use PDO which is modern API in PHP and a lot more secure when using it correctly with prepared statement ! But you can also use MYSQLI which is more similar to the MYSQL !*

You have to export your data from return array :

Using PDO :

```
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=".$hostname.";dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password);

$query = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM vraag1");

    $query -> execute (array ());

    $rows = $query -> fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo $id = $row["id"];
                    echo $vraag = $row["vraag "];
                    echo $AntwA = $row["AntwA "];
                    echo $AntwB = $row["AntwB "];
                    echo $AntwC = $row["AntwC "];
                    echo $AntwD = $row["AntwD "]; 
    }
```

Using MYSQLI :

```
$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM vraag1";
$rows = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
   echo $row["id"];
   echo $row["vraag"];
   echo $row["AntwA"];
   echo $row["AntwB"];
   echo $row["AntwC"];
   echo $row["AntwD"];
}
```

Comment: why should he use PDO?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Why he shouldn't ?!

Comment: Don't hear me wrong, I'm not saying he should't use PDO, but the OP looks like its comfortable with mysql, so we should guide him to use the correct apis.. remember mysqli does support prepared statements also.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sorry, I really understood you on wrong way :D i'm agree with you about mysqli, I personally think the PDO is more cleaner than mysqli, that's why I recommend that :) and maybe he don't know about PDO yet ! I will update my answer too :p thx anyway.

Comment: great, don't change your answer just add both methods so he can choose :)

Comment: @Jelles no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `mysql` function you are using is depreciated and no longer supported. you should use mysqli or pdo instead with prepared statements.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "lotto";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD FROM vraag1";
$test = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($test) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test)) {

       echo "ID : ".$row['id']."<br>";
       echo "vraag :".$row['vraag']."<br>";
       echo "AntwA :".$row['AntwA']."<br>";
       echo "AntwB :".$row['AntwB']."<br>";
       echo "AntwC :".$row['AntwC']."<br>";
       echo "AntwD :".$row['AntwD']."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "no results found";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For select function mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
so your assignment statement

```
$test = mysql_query($sql);
```

assign the resource to $test.

if you want the data inside the resource you can do

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($test)):
    print_r($row);
endwhile;
```

also you can access the $row['column_name']

If you want to return only one row you can do this limit in query

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD FROM vraag1 limit 1';
```

Comment: Not quite sure why this was downvoted, it is technically correct (though you also shouldn't be encouraging people to keep using the obsolete mysql_* functions)

Comment: @GordonM maybe was downvoted because he encourages people to use depreciated functions?

Comment: i'll take care from now

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Maybe, but if that was the case you'd think the downvoter would have the courtesy to leave a comment saying as much.  Downvotes without comments as for why aren't very helpful.

Comment: well @GordonM that have become a new culture of SO, people dv and leave,  see that everyday, answers just get downvote with no comments

Answer (score -1):

You need to add something like the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['vraag'];
    echo $row['AntwA'];
    echo $row['AntwB'];
    echo $row['AntwC'];
    echo $row['AntwD'];
}
```

Comment: First off it's mysql_fetch_assoc, secondly the mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5 and completely missing in PHP 7 and it does nobody any good to encourage people to keep using them.

Comment: I was going with his current code style as he wanted an answer, not to re-write his whole code! Instead of trolling why not add an answer

Comment: Pointing out how your answer needs improvement is not trolling.  If you think it is then I suggest you work on developing a thicker skin.

Answer (score -2):

use mysqli instead of mysql

```
<?php 
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';

   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    mysqli_select_db('lotto');   
    $sql = 'SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD FROM vraag1';
    $test = mysqli_query($sql);
    echo $test;   

?>
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Informatica\SE.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Informatica\SE.php on line 17

Comment: Your code still won't fix the problems with the original version and introduces new ones.

Comment: `mysqli` is not a clone of `mysql`