# Echo something into div MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select some data from a database and display that in HTML.

I thought the code below would work but it doesn't.

What code should I use instead?

And does the CSS still work that way?

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="se.css">
    <title>Lotto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "lotto";
    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    $query = "SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD,id FROM vraag1";
    $rows = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
    {
        echo "<div id='Vraag'>$row["vraag"];</div>";
    }
    ?>
    <div id="headerbg"></div>
    <center>
        <h1>Vraag 1</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img6">
        </div>

        <div id="plaatje">
            <img id="img1" src="wip.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="BGantA">
            <img id="img2" src="antw.png">
        </div>
        <div id="antA">
            <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antBB">Antwoord B</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antCC">Antwoord C</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antDD">Antwoord D</a>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If "nothing happens", either the query was unsuccessful (and you should get some errors/warnings about this in your log) or there was no rows returned, for that you can check with `echo $rows->num_rows;` after the query. You should also not use the same ID for each div like that, IDs should always be unique. To check for errors, add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the top of your file, and use `$db->error` to get any errors from the query. http://php.net/mysqli.error, EDIT: Should be `echo "<div id='Vraag'>".$row["vraag"]."</div>";` instead

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
   echo "<div id='Vraag'>$row["vraag"];</div>";
}` this will echo many dives with the same id

Comment: I also believe you just did ask this question today, but you have multiple accounts, this is  the same question you asked earlier and it was answered. check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386579/echo-something-out-mysql-database/42387746#42387746

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echo something out MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386579/echo-something-out-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of your echo code

```
echo "<div id='".$row['id']."'>".$row['vraag']."</div>";
```

Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.Change your code to this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
    {
        echo "<div id='Vraag'>".$row["vraag"]."</div>";
    }
```

Note: To get different id for each div use a counter(you can use your table id).

Comment: Errors are gone so it is working but I don't see anything on the screen or the id didn't work what happened? And CSS doesn't allow numbers as ID

Comment: @JellesD. do `print_r($row);exit;`  inside while loop and see if your sql is giving the data. and why selecting id twice.

Answer (score 0):

its a good practice to check if your query does return results.

this `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) { echo "<div id='Vraag'>$row["vraag"];</div>"; }` will output many div's with the same ID and ID needs to be different, so you need to have your ` before you start the loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="se.css">
    <title>Lotto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "lotto";
$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD,id FROM vraag1";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    // output data of each row?>

    <div id="Vraag">
    <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {

        echo $row["vraag"];

    }
} else {
    echo "no results found";
}?>

</div>
    ?>
        <div id="headerbg"></div>
    <center>
        <h1>Vraag 1</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img6">
        </div>

        <div id="plaatje">
            <img id="img1" src="wip.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="BGantA">
            <img id="img2" src="antw.png">
        </div>
        <div id="antA">
            <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antBB">Antwoord B</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img4">
        </div>
        <div>   
            <a href="#" id="antCC">Antwoord C</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antDD">Antwoord D</a>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have concatenate problem .

Replace the line

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
    echo "<div id='Vraag'>$row["vraag"];</div>";
}
```

with

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
    echo "<div id='Vraag_".$counter."' class='VraagClass'>".$row['vraag']."</div>";
}
```

I have added a counter to prevent generating duplicate div with the same Id.

Comment: then he should have multiple css styles?

Comment: In such a case he can add some class

Comment: Then it makes sense